# ImageIO.read() failing with no exception and a vaild url

Tags: java, java-io

I'm have the following code which I seem to be experiencing random image reading failure with with no exceptions. I'm running the following image url in a batch job, some of the other urls work some don't. The failure is ImageIO.read is null although it's a perfectly good working url. The url posted is the one I was experiencing the failure with. Anybody know what might be causing this code to fail.

I'd also like to say I'm using Java 8 as well.

```
   try {            
        URL url;

        url = new URL("https://content.homenetiol.com/672/27185/640x480/4d352f4ff9cf4948a93612e91401e128.jpg");

        BufferedImage sourceImg = ImageIO.read(url);
        System.out.println(sourceImg);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

also a working url

```
https://content.homenetiol.com/672/27185/640x480/49a9236f2196432db81e477fde44e756.jpg
```

Comment: Define "failure". If you're not getting an exception, then what is happening that you consider a failure? Also, your output in the `IOException` catch is wrong.

Comment: As i said, sourceImg is null, you can try that code on your own, you'll probably see the same thing happening.

Comment: The code works for me. I get sourceImg filled with `BufferedImage` object, not `null`.

Comment: It seems to be random, I had thousands of these just fail. See if any of these give you the same result. https://content.homenetiol.com/672/27185/640x480/e20746ab38554072bb9da30a77c2fcbe.jpg https://content.homenetiol.com/672/27185/640x480/e0f670f68f0c4f4cba0d0eb61298a348.jpg

Comment: Now I just ran that same code and it failed with a null pointer. I'm very confused.

Comment: I'm using Java 8, could that be the issue?

Comment: I may have figured this out, might be a cache issue, when I added this code it seemed to work             javax.imageio.ImageIO.setUseCache(false);

Comment: The issue (I think) is that occasionally the server redirects (302) the URL, and the `URL` class does not handle this correctly.  You need to use a HTTP client that deals with redirects correctly.

Comment: @CodeJunkie No, `setUseCache(false)` only disables disk caching. You are still caching, but now in memory. I did see your `null` image a couple of times, but when I run the program now, I only get an image... I bet it's the URL/external server that causes the issue.

Comment: Ah okay, could have been that random time it worked when I used the cache false. Do you have any recommendations for an HTTP client? I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: The documentation says that `null` may be returned if no image reader is found for the input. This suggests to me that sometimes the server simply sends back a non-image reply. Perhaps you should test this by running a simple URL connection many times, checking what mime type and content it returns each time.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll do that. I think I'm on the right path to resolving this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure from mucking around with `curl` that the server occasionally responds with 302 redirect response that the standard Java `URL` doesn't handle.

Here is some code that uses Apache HttpClient to fetch the image, and works even when the server responds with a 302 redirect:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://content.homenetiol.com/672/27185/640x480/4d352f4ff9cf4948a93612e91401e128.jpg");
  try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
       InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
    BufferedImage sourceImg = ImageIO.read(stream);
    System.out.println(sourceImg);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work perfectly. One quick question, will this code cause a degrade in performance, "not that the current code worked at all", but just curious. Again thanks.

Comment: The redirect will necessitate two requests, and this will likely be slower than if the server supplied the data on the first request, but as this is comparing something that doesn't give the right result with something that does, so I'm not sure the comparison is completely apt.  I don't think using HttpClient will be noticeably different in performance than using `URL` in the case where the server gives up the data on the first request.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` does indeed handle redirects, and it has an API for it.

Comment: I don't think `conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` will allow redirect from `https` to `http` protocols, which this particular server seems to require.  At least it won't in the sun/oracle implementation - see implementation of `followRedirect()` in `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?av=f#2308.